# Increasing the timout value passed to the call to request to WCF service over UWP device

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I'm able to send data to my WCF service from my test console application without any errors. The WCF testing tool also works without a problem. However when I try to send the same byte array to the WCF service from my Universal Windows Platform application I get the following error:

> The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I've been researching for a solution for hours but yet I couldn't fix this problem. I also don't think that sending just one byte array to the service should take a minute.

Here is the ServiceReferences.Designer.ClientConfig file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="IncreasedTimeOut" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
  <services>
   <service name="DServis.DenemeServis">
    <endpoint
       address="http://***.com/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="IncreasedTimeOut"
       contract="DenemeServis.IService"  />
   </service>
  </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Besides, I've also set these timeout values at codebehind just before the call to see if it makes any difference:

```
 _dServis.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
 _dServis.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
 _dServis.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
 _dServis.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

Again no chances. The exception is the same.

I'm sure it's client relevant as the service responses the calls from the console application as I've described at the start of my post. What may cause this issue?

**UPDATE:**

I have no wcf tracing error logs on server side (as expected). On the other hand, I've managed to set the timeouts at class implemention. Now, I'm getting "net_http_client_execution_error" while trying to send byte arrays. This gave me the clue that the device can't establish a connection while trying to send these types of data.

To go deeper on this issue, I've set up ngrok to test service behaviours. While trying to retrieve the smallest data from server, the device application threw "net_http_client_execution_error" again; however I get no errors if I call the method from my test console application. Now I'm sure that it's a device issue and working on how to fix it. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try:

1. Increase the sendTimeout value on the server side
2. Verify that you don't have a network communication error. (Eventually, disable for a quick test the firewall client side).
3. Enable WCF tracing in order to see what is the issue with your channel

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Ionut. My server sendTimeout is set to 10 minutes so it can't be the issue. There's also no network communication errors on the device as I can send and receive everything but byte arrays. My last chance is WCF tracing. I've enabled it on WCF service web.config however I will have to wait till tomorrow to see the logs because the system admin is not present. Will update the comment if I can catch anything useful.

Comment: @Doğa Gençer, I am facing a similar issue. Were you able to resolve yours?

Comment: Yeah. I've managed it done but I don't really reckon the process. Here is the bindings setting from the webconfig. Hope it helps: https://gist.github.com/lasuax/f351d92d3e495f3144d026acea6a45f9

Answer (score 1):

After setting the server side binding in web.config, I had to increase the sendtimeout in UWP client side as follows:

```
databaseClient = new CategoryDatabase.CategoryServiceClient();
databaseClient.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```